# jQuery dropable prevent sortable triggering

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two independent sortable lists, except on of them accept droppable items.

The problem is, when item from one list is being dropped to droppable list, update function is being triggered, and I need to prevent that, but I still need update function on both for sorting.

Here is the link to jsbin: https://jsbin.com/yuqebeyami/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding specific class to list from where you drop items, and in update function define If condition where it checks if item is dropped from other list.

```
if( !ui.draggable.hasClass("some-class") ) {
   /* Item is from same parent */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that still does not prevent from triggering sorting.

Comment: I cam provide you with a sample code. but can you provide working example on jsbin. The one you have posted is not working.